# Application_Start method in Globa.asax not getting hit

Tags: asp.net, iis, global-asax

I have tried doing an IISReset, and recyle and stop and start app pool, but I CANNOT get Application_Start to hit breakpoints.

Session_Start does get hit,  I have looked at other stackoverflow question and answers, but not helping

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {


        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AutoMapperConfig.RegisterMaps();


    }


    protected void Session_Start()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentUser"] = new User();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Load your app through the web browser.
2. Attach your debugger to your IIS process w3wp.exe.
3. Add a space to your web.config.
4. Hit your app again through the web browser.
5. Your application just recycled and app_start breakpoint should be hit.
6. Remove the space after you're done ;)

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio   "Unable to attach to the process.  An operation is not legal in the current state"

Comment: Oops, i tried to attach to chrome,   ok, so I attached to IIS and did the space in web.config, and refreshed browser but nothing get hit